# JSF Date Pattern issues

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to get date from database and display into data table. for example database date: 24/06/2015 but it display that date in data table date: 23/06/2015

The data table get date values from database but data table display previous date..

```
 Xhtml.code:
    <h:outputText class="text_ui" value="#{bean.date1}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>
```

please friends give me suggestion for displaying database date..

Comment: Are you sure that `bean.date1` returns the todays date?

Comment: Please never use word "problem" or "issue" in titles. Instead, describe the concrete problem/issue itself outright.

Comment: No .. bean.date1 get the stored date from database